# How to Insert Worksheet on Existing Document using Dev Express Office File API

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am Creating an xlsx Document after exporting i want to open it again and insert a Worksheet.

my references are as follow

```
    using DevExpress.Spreadsheet;
```

this is what i had outside my method

```
      IWorkbook MyBook = null;
```

inside my method i have this

```
     using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {

                        MyBook.LoadDocument(path, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
                        MyBook.Worksheets.Insert(count, "reportExel");
                    }
```

Comment: What's the question/problem ? Do you get errors with the code shown?

Comment: Ass soon as I get to the LoadDocument an exception is thrown saying that: "The object reference was never assigned to an Object instance."

Comment: Please tag what product are you using, IWorkbook interface is from NPOI or SpreadSheetGear, but LoadDocument sintax looks more like DevExpress, there are more program and logic errors but first let's identify the product...

Comment: its a Devepress product

Answer (score 0):

LoadDocument method has two overloads: From string and from file, in your approach, you are opening the file via stream, but sending stream.Name (string that gets the file path), you are calling the From file overload, it may throw a file in use error.

If you want to use Stream

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

// Load a workbook from the stream. 
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
{
    workbook.LoadDocument(stream, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
}

workbook.Worksheets.Insert(count, "reportExel");
```

If you want to use File

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

// Load a workbook from the file. 
workbook.LoadDocument(path, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
workbook.Worksheets.Insert(count, "reportExel");
```

**PS** Seeing your last update `IWorkbook MyBook = null;` is the problem, when you are trying to call LoadDocument from a null reference, you need to assign a value to `MyBook` variable  `IWorkbook MyBook = new Workbook();` is accepted since `Workbook` class implements `IWorkbook` interface